# Querys complejos con Patron repositorio

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, patrones-de-diseño, arquitectura, arquitectura-de-software

Estoy construyendo un proyecto con Web API y para esto me estoy basando en la arquitectura Onion.

Para separar las capas estoy usando el Patrón Repositorio (Repository Pattern) para el acceso a datos y una capa más arriba está la capa de servicios.

En la capa de servicios inyecto los repositorios y de esa manera puedo hacer un CRUD de una manera muy limpia y todo está perfectamente separado.

Lo que no me gusta es que cuando tengo la necesidad de hacer una operación más complicada con `linq` como un `join`, primero tengo que llamar al Repositorio de la tabla X y ejecutar un `Get` para obtener datos, después tengo que hacer esa misma operación con el Repositorio de la tabla Y.

Una vez tenga estos datos puedo hacer un `join`, esto no es óptimo ya que antes de hacer el `join` tengo que hacer 2 llamadas a la base de datos para obtener los datos.

He buscado en Google pero no encuentro una solución para este defecto de diseño, alguien más se ha encontrado con este problema? qué solución han implementado?

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: No del todo @fredyfx, mi lógica es la siguiente: cuando ocupo hacer joins mas complicados primero analizo a que repositorio seria mas afin la consulta y sobre esa programo el query. Para este problema en especifico utilice Dapper

Comment: Quizás esto te sea de utilidad: https://barradevblog.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/el-patron-repositorio-repository-pattern-implementacion-practica-con-entity-framework/ y http://fernandoescolar.github.io/2013/01/07/patrones-de-diseo-repository/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy bien, planteare la soluciion que encontre a mi problema.

En mi modulo principal, llamada dashboard que muestra una especie de mini-reporte, este reporte es una consulta en base de datos que involucra tres tablas (clientes, crédito y pagos).

Mi problemática es que quería hacer un join de la tabla clientes con la tabla pagos  y créditos. Para lograr esto tenia que hacer una consulta a tres repositorios,  primero obtener la información de clientes, después la información de créditos y por ultimo la información de pagos, y por ultimo hacer un join con los tres conjuntos de datos.

Obviamente no es un enfoque optimo ya que son demasiadas llamadas a la base de datos.
La verdad no se cual sea el enfoque mas optimo para resolver este problema, mi conclusión es que no se el patrón repositorio no es lo mejor para este tipo de escenarios.

La forma en la que resolví esto es la siguiente:
Este query me parecio mas apropiado dejarlo en un método dentro del repositorio Clientes, con un nombre muy especifico (ObteneReporteDepagosDelMes) y dentro de este método escribí la consulta linq que involucra los tres modelos.